# Joi.string().email() gives Error: Built-in TLD list disabled in React

Tags: reactjs, email-validation, joi

I'm using joi (version: "17.7.0") for email validation in reactjs. However i'm getting the following error :  `Error: Built-in TLD list disabled`. Because of this i'm not able to validate the domain name.
Eg: when I used joi in nodejs it correctly validated `umavah@mailto.pls` as false but in rectjs with TLD list disabled the same is validated as true.

I found this issue raised in git https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/2390 however i couldn't find a solution there.

How can i solve this  `Error: Built-in TLD list disabled` in reactjs  or is there any alternative to verify email domain name in react?

Answer (score 3):

You can replace `.email()` with `.email({ tlds: { allow: false } })` as shown below to solve the error.

```
{
    email: Joi.string().email({ tlds: { allow: false } }).required(),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below also works for me as stated by [JuroOravec](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/2390#issuecomment-1595763746)

```
Joi.string().email({ tlds: false });
```